# How to get recent events in RxJS that occurred in one second?

Tags: redux, rxjs, rxjs6

I have one Observable (redux Epic). I try group events by time. I use bufferTime but this operator not wait for first action :(

```js
        action$.pipe(
            ofType("SOME_REDUX_ACTION"), // custom filter operator 
            bufferTime(1000),
            tap((events) => console.log("WHY?", events))
            filter(events => !!events.length),
            [...]
```

Current output :

```
WHY? []
WHY? []
WHY? []
WHY? []
WHY? []
WHY? []
WHY? []
WHY? [event1,event2]
WHY? []
WHY? []
WHY? []
WHY? [event3]
```

Expected output without filter.

```
WHY? [event1,event2]
WHY? [event3]
```

Comment: So you want to start buffering when the first value arrives and then each 1s?

Comment: I would like bufferTime not to be "looped".I am concerned about the performance of my application. I have to filter empty data every second to achieve the expected effect

Comment: So what should be the buffering logic, then?

Comment: 1 wait for event
2 when event arrive start count 1 second and group all next events (during the 1 second).
3 emit event with grouped events and stop timer
4 again wait for event and if it appears start new 1  second timer

Comment: I would like to achieve a similar effect to "debounceTime", however, to know all the events that came during a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this:

```js
actions$ = actions$.pipe(share())

actions$.pipe(
  buffer(
    actions$.pipe(debounceTime(1000))
  )
  /* ... */
)
```

When `event1` arrives, it will be added to the internal `buffer` and the timer(from `debounceTime`) will start. If `event2` arrives before the timer ends, it will be added to that `buffer` and a new timer(`1s`) will be started. When `1s` passes, the collected items will be sent, in this case `event1` and `event2`.

When `event3` arrives, it will be added to the `buffer` and if no other value arrives during `1s`, it will emit `event3`.